# Where does bitbucket pipeline store files after export to "C:/temp/"

Tags: c#, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm working on a project and we are using bitbucket pipelines for the first time.

We have a project that runs calculations and then exports the results to a CSV file to "C:/temp/". The name of the file is dynamic and bound with the time it ran, but I don't have an issue there.

The issue I have is that I want to check the CSV file with a pipeline, meaning that Somewhere on the bitbucket or pipeline (to be honest I don't really know) the file will be also exported to "C:/temp/"... How do I get to this file in the bitbucket or pipeline directory?

Something like:

`string[] CSVFiles = Directory.GetFiles("C:/temp/", "*.csv");`

was my initial idea but this seems to fail.

The stacktrace it gives is:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException : Could not find a part of the path '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/SMLDC.Tests/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/C:/temp'.  Stack Trace:     
at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.CreateDirectoryHandle(String path, Boolean ignoreNotFound)   
at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.Init()   
at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1..ctor(String directory, Boolean isNormalized, EnumerationOptions options)   
at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1..ctor(String directory, FindTransform transform, EnumerationOptions options, Boolean isNormalized)   
at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerableFactory.UserFiles(String directory, String expression, EnumerationOptions options)   
at System.IO.Directory.InternalEnumeratePaths(String path, String searchPattern, SearchTarget searchTarget, EnumerationOptions options)   
at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern)  
at SMLDC.Tests.IntegrationTest.Setup() in /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/SMLDC.Tests/IntegrationTest.cs:line 31
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer!

Bitbucket is apparently (duh) linux based... so it will never store in a windows based path.

changed to a linux path after a Enviroment.OSVersion.Platform check and it works.